# Nginx url rewrite rule problem

Tags: permalinks, nginx

I am facing a problem with the permalink. Urls like `http://example.com/sub-page/` works fine with the help of

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;`

Right now i am working on temporary link which is like `http://192.168.100.200/wordpress/`

Now the link `http://192.168.100.200/wordpress/sub-page/` doesn't work and gives

**500 Internal Server Error**

Note: I am using `webuzo` as my server control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your'e missing the subdirectory part relative to the `root` setting, try this instead:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
```

and you shouldn't need the `q=$uri` part.

For subdirectories `dir1` and `dir2`, you could wrap the `try_files` with  `locate` blocks, something like:

```
location /dir1/ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dir1/index.php?$args; 
    #...
}

location /dir2/ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dir2/index.php?$args; 
    #...
}
```

Comment: So, if i am going to do more temporary installs under http://192.168.100.200/ on a different folder, i will need to use a second try_files line with the root setting edited?

Comment: I updated the answer.